What is the difference between these two waves?
Both of them are called modifed sine waves. No matter what the value of alpha is, I can't obtain the second graph. How can these two graphs both be labeled as modified sine waves then?
When I research online, I find RMS, Fourier series, and THD formulas for the first one. Can these formulas be directly applied to the second graph? If not, how can I find the formulas for it?

The figure is taken from Daniel W. Hart, Power Electronics.


Well, obviously you can find the RMS, Fourier series, and THD by applying the definitions of those things to the waveform.  I never liked the term "modified sine wave", it's more like "crappy cheap inverter waveform in place of sine wave".

I actually don't remember these topics much, and starting over from the beginning of the book would probably take too much time. Is there something like a calculator available online for this? A more practical approach than doing it manually.

The second is out of phase by approx T/8 or 45°, so you cannot make them match by only verying alpha - note that the first has the midpoint of each dead-time on Pi and 2Pi, while the second has the beginning of the dead time at these points.

"modifed sine wave" is just a UPS / inverter sales term for "not-a-sine-wave"

Yes, the second graph cannot be obtained just by varying alpha, but it needs to be correct.
The difference is the lower diagram is just delayed in time. By amount of alpha.
Also they are not really modified sine waves, unless it just means same as rectangular pulses of alternating polarity and some duty cycle, which might have been gotten by rounding a sine wave to nearest integer or something.
If you think of just delaying the first signal, and these are continuous waves that repeat, then both have equal RMS and equal Fourier series.

Who on earth calls them modified sine waves??

@Justme The "modified sinewave" vernacular comes from those cheap Chineese DC to AC inverters and UPS consumer devices. The idea is that this is the simplest way to approximate the RMS of a sinewave with the most basic "PWM" possible - fixed frequency and fixed duty cycle. It's done because it's super cheap and requires no engineering. And you get the harmonics for free.
